# How to prevent backgroundColor of UISegmentedControl bleeding beyond segmented border

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I've noticed that when I set a color for UISegmentedControl.backgroundColor, the color bleeds beyond the edges of the control (though not beyond the view's bounds). Here's an example with the segmented control's background color set to white and the container view's background color set to gray: [image: http://i.imgur.com/yHYT14C.png]

I've set the AutoLayout constraints of the segmented control such that the intrinsicContentSize should be used, but I haven't seen anyone else posting about this problem

Note that the image above is the best I've been able to get it to look... before that it was bleeding over by about 3-4px.

I've tried configuring the view to clipSubviews and the layer backing the UIView to masksToBounds, but I didn't expect that to fix the problem since I assume the bleeding is contained inside the view's/layer's bounds.

Any suggestions or advice appreciated. If not I'll just have to create images to back the UISegmentedControl that fix the bleeding, but that's annoying to have to maintain, to say the least.

Comment: Accepted Leo's answer below. Setting the segmented control's backing layer cornerRadius property to something near the segmented control's cornerRadius will clip the background color bleeding. Just have to hope Apple doesn't muck with the corner radius ever again! :)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Set the segment control's layer's corner radius to 4.0. It should help. You may need to import QuartzCore to be able to access the layer's properties.

```
segment.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
segment.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Or if you have it in Interface Builder, you can set it under "layer.cornerRadius" in the "User Defined Runtime Attributes" box. This way you don't have to import QuartzCore if you're not already using it.

Comment: Great thinking guys - such a simple solution, I feel silly for not coming up with it myself. I appreciate the answer!

Comment: hrmm m segmented control seems to be leaking even further than the corners on the right hand side. I have 2 full lines of white pixels. so the corner radius tip is working on the left but not to the right

Comment: @Sam If you really want to be precise, you can use a mask layer to mask it exactly with pixel-perfect accuracy.

Comment: Ah I think the issue is only on ios 7.0.2 :( just tested on 7.1 and it's working fine. (or it could be the device - it wasn't working on an iPon touch 5G but does work on an iPhone 5C)

Comment: FWIW: In iOS 8 (haven't checked iOS 7 yet), I find a `cornerRadius` of 4.0 to be more accurate than 5.0. Small difference, but my OCD noticed it!

Comment: This is not a long term solution since Apple may change the corner radius of the `UISegmentedControl` in the future.

Comment: @Karmeye You are correct. For a proper solution, make sure to open a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Thanks @JacobRelkin your comment saved 75% of my time

Comment: It's not working when we set cornerRadius from UISegmentedControl.appreance().layer.cornerRadius...any solution so that I can make all segmentedControl rounded at once.

Comment: @NikhilManapure `CALayer` and its properties are not meant for and do not support `UIAppearance` API. Subclass your segment controls and use that subclass where needed.

Answer (score 9):

Set segment control layer corner radius to 5. and ClipsToBounds YES .

```
segmentController.layer.cornerRadius = 5;    
segmentController.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Hope its work for you

Comment: This does not seem to add anything useful to the previously given answer, posted almost a year ago, nor the additional information provided in the comments for that answer.

Comment: Don't be haters, this works. Even with the corner radius, I was getting a little bit of bleed, but was fixed with `clipsToBounds`

Comment: Thank you for the precise commands. One minor change: segmentController.clipToBounds = true (instead of YES).

Answer (score 4):

the best result I could achieve in Swift:

```
    segmentedControl.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, segmentedControl.bounds.size.width-1, segmentedControl.bounds.size.height);
    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: mask.frame,
                                byRoundingCorners: [.BottomLeft, .BottomRight, .TopLeft, .TopRight],
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 4.0, height: 4.0))
    mask.path = maskPath.CGPath
    segmentedControl.layer.mask = mask
```

Comment: This one produced the best results! Thank you!

Comment: On IOS 10, this one works perfectly for me, the other solutions appear to round the internal corners as well rather than having a clean vertical divide.